# Documenting using Sandcastle: Refering to enum value using <see>

Tags: c#, enums, msdn, sandcastle, xml-documentation

I'm using Sandcastle 2.4.10520 and Sandcastle Help File Builder 1.8.0 to generate a .chm help file.

In my documentation, I'm using `<see>` tags.

If I try to refer an enum like `<see cref="NumberStyles"/>` it works perfectly.

If I try to refer an enum value like `<see cref="NumberStyles.AllowTrailingWhite"/>` I get a link in the documentation file, but the link leads me to an [MSDN Page not found](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb493221)

I don't get any warnings - my xml documentation is correct.

I've noticed that MSDN pages that refer to an enum value also have a Page not found link.
For example: [UInt64.Parse Method (String, NumberStyles, IFormatProvider)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6z3t46t0%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) refers to `NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier` and this leads to another [MSDN Page not found](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles.allowhexspecifier%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Should I refer to the enum instead of the enum value?

What should I do to refer an enum? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that it's happening on MSDN doesn't bode well. Do the enum values have XML documentation?

If I remember correctly, there should be settings in SHFB that will let you force generation of documentation for members that don't have XML - or maybe it's a setting that lets you exclude members that don't have XML doc. Regardless, give the settings a good once over to make sure you aren't excluding the enum members that way.

Otherwise, it should generate documentation for every member, and enum values are members of types the same as a const or static field would be.

**EDIT:** It looks like at least on the newer MSDN site, individual enum values aren't given their own page. For example, take a look at the [NumberStyles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles(v=VS.100).aspx) enum. In that case, you might not have a better option than just linking to the enum.

Comment: I couldn't find a setting in SHFB that controls whether a link to a non-existing page should be created. I believe that Sandcastle is not aware to the fact that MSDN doesn't contain a separate page for the enum value.

Can I link to the specific enum value in the enum page?

Comment: That I don't know... it's been over a year since I've used Sandcastle/SHFB and my memory is a bit rusty. From what I remember, there are *a lot* of switches you can play with in the SHFB interface, so give it a few more lookings through to see if there's something else you can tweak to get the result you want. Sorry I can't offer better advice than that :\